# Having a custom repository not associated to an entity in Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Would be possible to have a custom repository not associated with an entity in Symfony 2 and Doctrine 2? I would like to put in it some native SQL that doesn't fit well in other repositories (it may refer to abstract or entity hierarchy).

How controller code `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepositoty(/* ??? */)` should be replaced?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's possible to have as many repositories as you wish. However, only a single repository can be linked with the entity manager.

You need to define a few services to add a custom repository.

```
<!-- My custom repository -->
<service id="acme.repository.my_entity" class="Acme\FQCN\MyEntityRepository" >
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
    <argument type="service" id="acme.metadata.my_entity" />
</service>

<!-- MyEntity metadata -->
<service id="acme.metadata.my_entity" class="Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData">
    <argument>Acme\FQCN\MyEntity</argument>
</service>
```

The repository class would have to inherit from `EntityRepository`.

```
namespace Acme\FQCN;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MyEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /** 
     * If you want to inject any custom dependencies, you'd have either have to
     * add them to the construct or create setters. I'd suggest using setters
     * in which case you wouldn't need to use the constructor in this class.
     *
     * public function __construct($em, Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $class, $custom_dependency)
     * {
     *     parent::__construct($em, $class);
     * }
     *
     */
}
```

Unfortunately you'll not be able to retrieve it via the doctrine service. Instead, retrieve it straight from the container:

```
$this->get('acme.repository.my_entity');
```

---

**EDIT**

If you're creating a repository that shouldn't be linked to any entities, simply create a service and inject the necessary dependencies.

```
<!-- Repository for misc queries -->
<service id="acme.repository.misc" class="Acme\FQCN\MiscRepsitory">
    <argument type="service" id="database_connection" />
</service>
```

Since you're not using any of the Doctrine's ORM features in a custom repository, there's no need to extend `EntityManager`.

```
namespace Acme\FQCN;

use \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class MiscRepository
{
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct(Connection $conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i was meaning that repository shouldn't be associated with any entity. So, why the metadata thing?

Comment: @Gremo in that case it would make sense to just create an additional service and inject a database connection itself.

Comment: after injecting database_connection i should only make a class that inherits from EntityRepository, am i right?

Comment: @Gremo Nope, since you're not actually using any of the ORM features, the repository wouldn't have to inherit from `EntityRepository` at all.

Comment: Fine. Thanks for your help, i'm going to accept the answer. The only bad thing of custom repository (with dependencies) is the need of define and pass the metadata. Creating a service for each entity metadata could be quite boring.

Comment: @Gremo Come to think of it, you wouldn't have to define the metadata. Instead, create the `MedaData` object inside your repository's constructor.

Answer (score 6):

I adopted a slightly different solution using Symfony2 parent services.

First of all I created a parent service, a `GenericRepository` class that exposes a couple of methods and makes life easier in case we'd like to refactor our code in the future.

`services.yml`

```
acme_core.generic_repository:
    abstract: true
    class: Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Repository\GenericRepository
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

`Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Repository\GenericRepository`

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * Class GenericRepository
 * @package Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Repository
 */
abstract class GenericRepository {
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager() {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
     */
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    abstract function getTable();
}
```

Now we want to define a new repository:

`services.yml`

```
# Repositories
acme_product.repository.product_batch:
    parent: acme_core.generic_repository
    class: Acme\Bundle\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductBatchRepository
```

`Acme\Bundle\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductBatchRepository`

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\ProductBundle\Repository;

use Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Repository\GenericRepository;

/**
 * Class ProductBatchRepository
 * @package Acme\Bundle\ProductBundle\Repository
 */
class ProductBatchRepository extends GenericRepository {
    /**
     * @param int $batchId
     * @return integer The number of affected rows.
     */
    public function deleteBatch($batchId) {
        $table = $this->getTable();

        return $this->getConnection()->delete($table, [
            'id' => $batchId
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTable() {
        return 'product_batch';
    }
}
```

The `deleteBatch()` method creates and executes the following query:

`DELETE FROM product_batch WHERE id = ?`

Finally in our controller:

```
public function deleteAction() {
    $batchId = $this->getRequest()->get('batchId');

    $affectedRows = $this->get('acme_product.repository.product_batch')->deleteBatch($batchId);

    return $this->render(/**/);
}
```

For further information and **entity manager** / **connection** usage please refer to the official documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to create a plain PHP class with the needed dependencies in the constructor and get it through the service container.