# How do I use more than one repository class in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I'm building an application in Symfony 2.2.

I use a custom repository class for one of my entities. I include it like this:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
```

I want to use methods on my category entites from two other repository classes.

```
 @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Sortable\Entity\Repository\SortableRepository")
 @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
```

The entity, however, only expects one repositoryClass. How can I use all three of these repositories for the same entity?

Comment: That's not possible. However, you can have multiple custom repositories set up as services. I've written about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411183#answer-11411353

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you can only have one repository per Entity. 
So you have referenced
`ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")`

If you must use another repositories within the repository,

You can get the EntityManager for those Repositories (if not same) eg: `$em2 = whatEverIsTheEntity()`

Now you can have proxy methods in CategoryRepository to the methods in the repository you want to use. eg: `$em2->getMethodFromEm2()`.

**Note:** But I ***wouldn't prefer*** above solution unless there is really a need. I would rather create a service layer which has Doctrine Entity Manager as Dependency Injected. This service layer will connect to all the repositories and collect final result whatever you want to achieve (to be used in the controller). This way, the code will be much cleaner and testable as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Repositories are class (so entity) reserved. If you inherit from super classes (even if those classes doesn't inherit directly, but repos can), than you can make your repository (`CategoryRepository`) extended by other two (one extend the other, since PHP doesn't allow more than one class extension).

Pretty much something like that

```
class NestedTreeRepository extends SortableRepository
{
}

class CategoryRepository extends NestedTreeRepository 
{
}
```

don't know if this fits your needs, but this a way (and I'll not surprised if is the only one) for realize what you're trying to do here

Comment: Thank you for your answer DonCallisto. Using your example, I can successfully let CategoryRepository extend NestedTreeRepository. I can not let NestedTreeRepository extend SortableRepository however: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class NestedTreeRepository because the name is already in use.

Comment: @Bohr: did you "import" them correctly? You have to write a `use` statement

Comment: Yes I import them correctly with a use statement. I do this in my CategoryRepository class. (I do not want to edit the other classes as they come from a bundle.) When I first `use` the NestedTreeRepository and then try to override it to make it extend SorteableRepository, I get the error from my last message.

Comment: @Bohr: one second, you haven't to override! You have to do that where you define those repos.

Comment: The issue is that those repos (NestedTreeRepository and SortableRepository) are installed from an external bundle, which I do not want to edit.

Comment: @Bohr: in that case, I don't know how to help you.

Comment: The "name is already in use error" can usually be eliminated with something like: "use SomeBundle\NestedTreeRepository as NestedTreeRepoBase;"  Basically, rename the class locally and then extend from it.

Comment: @Cerad: is what I mean, thought Bohr get it.