# Repository without entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, oop, dql

I have admin area on my site on symfony 3.4.
Login and pass for admin is stored in memory in security.yml

```
providers:
  users_db:
      entity:
        class: AppBundle:User
        property: email

admin_db:
    memory:
        users:
            admin:
                password: root
                roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
```

I also need a repository for DQL queries for admin (count of users, count of reviews, different settings). But I don't need entity admin (I store data for admin in memory in security.yml)
How I can create repository AdminRepository without creating entity admin. (I don't need table admin in my database!!!)

Comment: I think that you need a service not a AdminRepository. Inside this service you can use different repositories, for instance UserRepository to get users' count

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having a custom repository not associated to an entity in Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411183/having-a-custom-repository-not-associated-to-an-entity-in-symfony-2-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 0):

The InMemoryProvider does exactly that, store users in memory and not in a database. You cannot add, edit or delete users at runtime, as they are completely defined in that very YAML file.

See https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded:

> The easiest (but most limited) way, is to configure Symfony to load hardcoded users directly from the security.yaml file itself. This is called an "in memory" provider, but it's better to think of it as an "in configuration" provider.

So by using the provider with the `memory` config key, you have defined your users "in configuration" and you need to add/edit/remove them there.